# Reactor Core compilation issue

Tags: spring, java-8, spring-webflux

I am fairly new to Reactor-core and I am trying to understand the way it works. I found a sample program that I am trying to run but it is giving me error as below.

**Details** -> The method subscribe(Consumer<? super Integer>) in the type Flux is not applicable for the arguments (new Flow.Subscriber(){})

As far as I understand, It needs a Subscriber implementation to create a subscription in order to get data from flux.

Please help.

I executed it in JDK 8 and JDK 11 but same error comes on both JDK.

```
    public static void callCustomSubscribe() {
        List<Integer> elements = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        
//      Subscriber<Integer> subs = new SubscribeImpl();

        Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4)
          .log()
          .subscribe(new Subscriber<Integer>() { // Error comes here
            @Override
            public void onNext(Integer integer) {
              elements.add(integer);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable t) {}

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {}

            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Subscription subscription) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                subscription.request(Long.MAX_VALUE);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

no it doesen't need a custom `Subscriber` implementation to run. There are already several ones implemented in `Reactor`.

i dont really understand what it is you want to do with your pice of code. But you usually don't declare an external `ArrayList` and use that in lambdas. It's more like java streams where you do your transformations inside lambdas.

example:

```
Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4)
    .map(value -> {
        return value += 1;
    })
    .subscribe(n -> {
        System.out.println(n);
    });
```

I good way to start to understand reactor is to go through the beginning of the reactor documentation. [Simple ways to create a Flux or Mono and Subscribe to it](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_simple_ways_to_create_a_flux_or_mono_and_subscribe_to_it).

Your error is because you are using a [`Flow.Subscriber`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Flow.Subscriber.html) when what it actually wants is a [`Consumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html?is-external=true) which is a completely different interface. If you really want to implement a full subscriber a good start is to use a [`BaseSubscriber`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_an_alternative_to_lambdas_basesubscriber) as an abstract base and then override some functionality in it, but that is more en intermediate exercise.

Comment: Actually, the code I have put in here, is just to understand how to write a customer Subscription. Its not meant to do anything really so no need to brainstorm over why an external Arraylist is being used. Are you saying that Flow.Subscriber cannot be put inside the subscribe as that is what is being written in this website. LINK -> https://www.baeldung.com/reactor-core

Comment: If you read my answer im not saying anything like that. Im explaining what your error message is telling you. If i was to guess is that you have mixed up your imports and you are importing `Flow.Subscriber` instead of the `Subscriber` interface from the package `org.reactivestreams` http://www.reactive-streams.org/reactive-streams-1.0.0-javadoc/org/reactivestreams/Subscriber.html which is used in the baeldung blog.

Comment: if you look in the Flux api you can see that there are several implementations of the `subscribe` function, one that takes a `consumer`, and one that takes a `Subscriber` from the `org.reactivestreams` package. So make sure you have correct imports https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html